# Sparql: Get individuals with given data property

Tags: sparql

Being totally new to SPARQL and RDF(s) I'm apologizing in advance if my question seem a little stupid, and I should know better.

Anyways my ontologi goes somewhat like this. All the subclasses got instances of spesific wine, for example "Dupont Pome". The different wines may have several data properties like "year", "volume", "grapeType" etc.

How would I set up a query in which can fetch out one or more individual with the spesific xsd:string in the grape type property or the volume property which is an xsd:positiveInteger?

```
owl:things
----------wine
--------------redWhine
--------------whiteWine
--------------fooWine
```

I'm not entirely sure that I'm formulering my question very well, so please correct if I'm messing up terminologies and such.

Also I would have included what my query looked like so far if I really knew where to begin. The only statements in which I can get any results so far in my experience with SPARQL, is getting all the subclasses in relation to their superclass in a table.

Comment: You might try working with a GUI-based SPARQL query builder, like [iSPARQL](http://oat.openlinksw.com/index.html?isparql), [live here on the DBpedia endpoint](http://dbpedia.org/isparql/) from [OpenLink Software](https://www.openlinksw.com/), primary sponsor of the public DBpedia endpoint and my employer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?s WHERE {?s <VOLUME_PROPERTY_URI> "VOLUME_VALUE"^^xsd:positiveInteger}
```